# Align radioGroup buttons horzintally

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, radio-button

I have search many times to align each radio button in radio group horizontally

but no luck , note : i have many radio group each radio group at buttom of another and so on .

and some radio group has three radio buttons or just two radios

how can i fix it's align ?

note : i want to align the radio button it self not the radio text

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context=".DartboardActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/game_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="فحص قياس الزيت"
        android:textColor="@color/FontColorLogin"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="90dp"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/checkbox_background"
            android:text="غير كامل"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/FontColorLogin"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/checkbox_background"
            android:text="كامل"
            android:textColor="@color/FontColorLogin"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="فحص جودة الزيت"
        android:textColor="@color/FontColorLogin"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/checkbox_background"
            android:text="محترق"
            android:textColor="@color/FontColorLogin"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/checkbox_background"
            android:text="غير كامل"
            android:textColor="@color/FontColorLogin"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/checkbox_background"
            android:text="كامل"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/FontColorLogin"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#333"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gallery" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/camera" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/syncoff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/save" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried a GridView?

Comment: what do you mean by align? do you want to have all of them in just one horizontal line?

Comment: Yes i wanna to make first column for first radio for each group and second column for second radio and so one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start using layout_weight property.
This property aligns controls properly.

**Edit:**

Man there are way too many errors in your layout

1. Orientation in relative layout
2. Button LinearLayout properties
3. Layout_weight property being used twice
   etc.

Dont you get errors in your XML???

**Edited:-**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".DartboardActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/game_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="hello"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="hello"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="hello"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="hello"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="hello"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#333"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i have used it in every radio button , but no effect

Comment: try using `LinearLayout`

Comment: yes each radio button start as above one starts, and so on

Comment: there are errors in your layout itself..im checking it by the way

Comment: i have fixed all error , but still not get I want :) . , i'm uses layout_weight in all radio button but not no effect done

Comment: are your relative layout and linear layout in the same XML???
Because...if a relative layout starts..it must end at the end too...

Comment: yes i have two one for body and one for footer and one for upper layout " father "

Comment: same thing no new effect

Comment: hows that possible???i edited my answer with new code..i changed your relative layout and other things..i changed texts too...

Comment: try this code now..i re-edited something..check it out

Comment: ok it's nice now but i want to decrease the spaces between this two radio button , cuz it there much space

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted..and spaces cant be managed now..its the weight which decides it...try and hope you will get it right as rain.. :-)